# Can app be programmed to trigger an action, when specific cell tower is used?

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, tracking, wakeup

I would like a tracking app to change tracking settings like distance filter, when users phone is in a certain area. We are not happy with the geo-fence-solution. So my question is: 
Is it possible to make an app detect, that cell tower xy is used by phone and can this be used to change settings?
Example: When iphone or android phone is using cell tower "23445234234" use a distance filter of 10 meters. If device is not using this cell tower use "signifant location change only" setting. 
Thanks for helping!

Comment: I have an android app called Lama that does this (though I haven't actually seen it succeed).  So at least in theory it is possible.  I can't really tell you anything about how it works.

Answer (score 0):

As to my knowledge, iOS does not disclose such information to the application via public APIs.

Comment: Ok. Not, what I like to hear, but thanks for the quick answer.